# redirect to parent Rails app's route from within engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

So I have a Rails engine contained within a Rails app. I want to do something like `redirect_to @record.polymorphic_relationship` in one of my engine's controllers, where `@record.polymorphic_relationship` is a `Picture`, which is a model in the parent app. There's a `picture_path` path helper in the parent Rails app.

I feel like I ought to be able to redirect from within the engine to a route in the parent app using `main_app` somehow. Just doing `redirect_to @record.polymorphic_relationship` inside an engine controller doesn't work, because it complains no `picture_url` route exists. This same code works from within a controller in the parent app.

If I do `redirect_to main_app.send("#{@record.polymorphic_relationship_type.downcase}_path", @record.polymorphic_relationship)`, it works, but this seems hacky. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Have you found a better way of doing this?

Comment: Thanks heaps! I've been at it for an hour..

Answer (score 6):

`redirect_to main_app.url_for(@record.polymorphic_relationship)`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It works like a charm in rails 5.1.3. `main_app` is a helper that gives you access to application's routes inside Engine  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#class-Rails::Engine-label-Using+Engine-27s+routes+outside+Engine